# A table with `\hline`s in a tikzposter block

Tags: tabularx, width, tikzposter, hline

I would like to have a table with `\hline`s fit inside of a tikzposter block, but the lines stretch outside of the block, as shown in the following image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \block{Kysymyspatterin kysymykset}{
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|p{0.4\textwidth}}
           Numero& Kysymys (3--9 määrällisiä, loput laadullisia) \\
           \hline\hline
           1& Text here\\
           \hline
           \end{tabularx}

    }

\end{document}
```

How could the length of the `\hline`s be limited to the width of the table? Changing the second column to the `X` type does nothign to alleviate the issue.

Comment: By NOT using `tabularx` if you don't have at least one `X` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple: use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \block{Kysymyspatterin kysymykset}{
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X}
           Numero& Kysymys (3--9 määrällisiä, loput laadullisia) \\
           \hline\hline
           1& Text here\\
           \hline
           \end{tabularx}

    }

\end{document}
```

[image]